# Showing that the following conditions are equivalent:

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. We say that $D \subset  X$ is dense in $(X, d)$ if $\bar D = X$.

Let $D \subset  X$. Show that the following conditions are each equivalent:

1. $D$ is dense in $(X, d)$.
2. $\overset{\circ}{D^c}=\emptyset$
3. $\forall x \in X, d(x,D) = 0$.
4. $\forall A\subset X$, $\overset{\circ}{A}=\emptyset\implies \overset{\circ}{A}\cap D=\emptyset $.

Comment: Your question would sound a lot more polite if you were to include some kind of context, what your own thoughts on the problems are, where exactly you got stuck etc. Writing it like this seems a bit like "Hey guys, wanna do my homework for me?".

Comment: In addition of what @Some Math Student said,  I think 2) and 4) are not true, may be a taypo errors

Comment: Sorry I must have hit post on this question before finishing to write what I wanted to say. Didn't mean to sound rude. I have issues proving that statements are equivalent as I dont know how many steps are required to show that all 4 statements are equivalent.

Comment: @user183719, see my post. After you corrected your fourth sentence.

Comment: thank you @mitsos I will work through your solution now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2: For a set $A\subset X$ we have that $(X\setminus A)^o=X\setminus \overline A$

3:$d(x,D)= inf\{d(x,y):y\in D\}$. $D$ is dense in $X$ thus there is a sequence $(y_n)\subset D):y_n\to x$.

4:You want to prove that $A^o\neq \emptyset\Rightarrow {A^o}\cap D\neq \emptyset$.

This is because the dense $D$ intersects with every open set because :

$x\in \overline D \Leftrightarrow \forall G:x\in G$ and $G$ is open we have that $G\cap D\neq \emptyset$.

Here $\overline D =X$ and thus we have all the open sets, including $A^o$.

Comment: You mean $\overline D = X$, right? not $x$ :P

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva, yes. keyboard mistakes:P

Answer (score 0):

1) is equivalent to 2) since $\overline{D}$ is the smallest closed set containing $D$, $\mathrm{int}(D^c)$ is the biggest open set contained in $D^c$ and 
$$
\mathrm{int}(D^c) = \overline D^c.
$$
The definition of $d(x,D)$ is $\mathrm{inf}_{y \in D} d(x,y)$. So clearly $d(x,D) > 0$ if and only if $x \in \mathrm{int}(D^c)$, which proves the equivalence of 2) and 3).

There is a problem with 4) ; if you read it correctly it is true for any set $D$ (I mean ANY set, not just those subsets of $X$... ) can you make sure you didn't write the statement wrong? ;)

Hope that helps,

Comment: Hi, sorry just had another look at my post and realised that part 4 should read: for any set A ⊂ X, we have A∘ not equal to ∅ ⟹A∘∩D not equal to ∅.

Comment: @user183719 : Makes more sense!